# Получить все комментарии HtmlUnit Java

Tags: java

Как можно получить:

- все комментарии на странице;
- или содержимое определённой строки страницы.

  //Получаем HtmlPage

  HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://SITE.RU"));

Пробовал следующие способы

```
//div норм. выводит, а вот комментарии как я написал выше не хочет.
List<?> out = htmlPage.getByXPath("//!--");

//Выводит полное содержимое, но хочется получить именно комментарии.
String out = htmlPage.asXml();
```

--
P.S. Добавьте метку HtmlUnit

Comment: > P.S. Добавьте метку HtmlUnit
нет смысла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с XPath, конечно не заработает. XPath предназначен для обработки элементов и их атрибутов. Комментарии не относятся к элементам, поэтому выпадают из поля зрения XPath.

Выдачу второго варианта можно обработать регэкспом, но, к счастью, это необязательно. Все решается имеющимися средствами:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HtmlPage page = new WebClient().getPage("http://site.ru/");
    printComments(page);
}

public static void printComments(DomNode node) { 
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (DomNode child: node.getChildren()) {
            printComments(child);
        }
    } else {
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Всё работает!

Comment: RTFM спасет мир ;)

Comment: У меня пока видимо с логикой и пониманием проблемы :)
Я честно старался читать FM в течение 4-5 часов